# How to start threads at the same time when I use executors?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I have wrote following code:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
long start= System.currentTimeMillis();
ArrayHolder arrayHolder = new ArrayHolderBySynchronized();
List<Runnable> runnables = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < readerThreadCount; i++) {            
    es.submit(new ArrayReader(arrayHolder));
}
for (int i = 0; i < writerThreadCount; i++) {
    es.submit(new ArrayWriter(arrayHolder));
}
es.shutdown();
boolean finshed = es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
long finished= System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(finished-start);
```

As I understand after execution code:

```
es.submit(new ArrayReader(arrayHolder));
```

new thread can begun execute.

I want to allow to start thread only when I submit all tasks.

I know that I can achieve it if I use `CountDouwnLatch`.  But I want to know can I achieve it if I use `ExecutorServise`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `invokeAll` method. From docs:

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their
>   status and results when all complete. Future.isDone is true for each
>   element of the returned list. Note that a completed task could have
>   terminated either normally or by throwing an exception. The results of
>   this method are undefined if the given collection is modified while
>   this operation is in progress.

```
<T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)
        throws InterruptedException;
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually, you can't rely on the time when task execution starts and order of tasks. If you submitted all tasks you can't be sure that they will be executed in some amount of time or before some event. It depends on thread scheduling, you can't control it's behaviour. Even if you submit all tasks at the same time it does not imply that they will be executed at the same time.

Comment: problem that I have Runnable tasks

Comment: change them to Callable, it's not a big deal

Comment: CountDownLatch gives more control?

Comment: @gstackoverflow, you can't control threads in this way. You can control threads interaction, happens before relations. `CountDownLatch` helps you to stop execution until some conditions are met. But you can't control when some thread actually starts to execute it's code, i.e. changes its state from *runnable*  to *running*. It's done by thread scheduler. You just can;t rely on it!

Comment: No, using `CountDownLatch` or another concurrent structure you can get pretty close to desirable behaviour, but still can't be sure. Using `CountDownLatch` you can be sure that all threads are submitted. But after that you can't predict actual execution.